# I roll a fair die repeatedly until I get $6$, what is the probability that neither $1$ nor $2$ occurs before $6$ appears.

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

I roll fair a die repeatedly until I get $6$, what is the probability that neither $1$ nor $2$ occurs before $6$ appears.

Not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is the chance that you *win* on turn $k$?

This occurs when all prior rolls of the dice were numbered either $3,4,$ or $5$ and then finally on turn $k$ you roll a $6$.

This occurs then with probability $(\frac{1}{2})^{k-1}\cdot \frac{1}{6}$

Range over all possible values of $k$ for the result.

> $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{2})^{k-1}\cdot \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{3}$

Alternatively, since if a $3,4$ or $5$ are rolled, you essentially go back to square one, you may opt to ignore those as possibilities.  If you roll a die with only three sides, labeled $1,2,6$, the game is guaranteed to end in one turn.

> This also gives the probability $\frac{1}{3}$ for success.

Comment: simple and too the point. great answer

Comment: @krossreg The singular of the word is **die**, not *dice*.  Dice is plural.  My answer already assumed that the die was fair since otherwise there was not enough information to answer.  Indeed $\frac{1}{6}$ is the probability that on a specific roll you roll a six, just as the probability of rolling a $3,4,$ or $5$ on a single roll is $\frac{1}{2}=\frac{3}{6}$.  Regardless, the calculations are already included above.  $\frac{1}{6}$ is not the final answer.

Comment: Okay, thank for such a simple explanation.

Comment: A really nice and elegant answer. I loved the part with that infinite sum.

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that my answer also assumes that the die in question is six-sided.  It should be stated in problems since there also exist four-sided, eight-sided, ten-sided, twelve-sided,... and many more types of dice.  If left unspecified, the most common to appear in problems are six-sided dice, but to be completely unambiguous, it really should be included in the problem statement.  Interestingly enough, the probability is the same for any shape die of with at least six sides and each number appearing on only one of the sides.